# Convert cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to convert this curl command into php:

```
 curl -X POST "https://onfleet.com/api/v2/tasks"        -u "456798b4f32516d4c75cf80bacc6f32a:"        -d '{"destination":{"address":{"unparsed":"2829 Vallejo St, SF, CA, USA"},"notes":"Small green door by garage door has pin pad, enter *4821*"},"recipients":[{"name":"Blas Silkovich","phone":"+16505554481","notes":"Knows Neiman, VIP status."}],"completeAfter":1455151071727,"notes":"Order 332: 24oz Stumptown Finca El Puente, 10 x Aji de Gallina Empanadas, 13-inch Lelenitas Tres Leches","autoAssign":{"mode":"distance"}}'
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You need to use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or if you don't want to use a new extension, you can use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Client URL Library (cURL)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). The `-u` is setting the username (with no password) so use `CURLOPT_USERPWD`. `-d` sets the data so use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://onfleet.com/api/v2/tasks');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'xxxxxxxxxxxx:');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"destination":{"address":{"unparsed":"2829 Vallejo St, SF, CA, USA"},"notes":"Small green door by garage door has pin pad, enter *4821*"},"recipients":[{"name":"Blas Silkovich","phone":"+16505554481","notes":"Knows Neiman, VIP status."}],"completeAfter":1455151071727,"notes":"Order 332: 24oz Stumptown Finca El Puente, 10 x Aji de Gallina Empanadas, 13-inch Lelenitas Tres Leches","autoAssign":{"mode":"distance"}}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks jksn.co, it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm doing with Curl + PHP:

```
    <?php

    //Onfleet API credentials
    $username = 'XXXX'; 
    $api = '456798b4f32516d4c75cf80bacc6f32a';

    // Apply custom curl request to url
    $url = "https://onfleet.com/api/v2/tasks";   

    // Give parameters
    $fields = array(
    'destination'=> '2829 Vallejo St, SF, CA, USA',
    'recipients'=> 'Blas Silkovich'
    );

    // intiate curl request
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_GETFIELDS,$params);

    // set the number of post fields
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $fields);
    // set the fields
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r($result);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I'm trying to use Onfleet API. Apparently I need to pass an array in the params array according to the example curl request and Onfleet Docs: http://docs.onfleet.com/docs/tasks

What do you think?

Comment: You just need to JSON encode the $field variable - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Have you tried encoding: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, json_encode ($fields));

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete clean implementation:

```
 <?php

    //Onfleet API credentials
    $username = 'xxxxxx'; 
    $api = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $url = "https://onfleet.com/api/v2/tasks";  

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"destination":{"address":{"unparsed":"2829 Vallejo St, SF, CA, USA"},"notes":"Small green door by garage door has pin pad, enter *4821*"},"recipients":[{"name":"Blas Silkovich","phone":"+16505554481","notes":"Knows Neiman, VIP status."}],"completeAfter":1455151071727,"notes":"Order 332: 24oz Stumptown Finca El Puente, 10 x Aji de Gallina Empanadas, 13-inch Lelenitas Tres Leches","autoAssign":{"mode":"distance"}}');

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($result);

?>
```